# Set Welcome Page before main program

Tags: java, timer

I'm trying to create a simple welcome page that appears and disappears after a few seconds before my main program pops up. just wish to use simple JFrame and JPanel with a image, there after implement a delay before running my main program.

i have created my JFrame and JPanel with image, i'm not too sure which timer delay function to use

Comment: [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1KMZB_enUS562US562&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20timer&safe=off) your tags. Then remember you are using swing. Then click the second link. This is just to start.

Comment: You can use a simple `Thread` sleep.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera `Thread sleep` doesn't works fine in `swing` because it stops the thread, a `Timer` don't, it doesn't freeze the App, so you can still running process on 2nd plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) for a working example.

> i have created my JFrame and JPanel with image, i'm not too sure which timer delay function to use

Or, if you want to reinvent the wheel and do it all yourself then you would use a `Swing Timer`. The tutorial also has a link on `How to Use Swing Timers`.